# Components from Vue plugin (comp lib) register but won't mount

Tags: typescript, vue.js, plugins, sass

I'm building a component library in Vue with Typescript and Sass. So the way to do this in Vue is to create a Vue plugin, right?

For a month I've been struggling with this already. The components from my Vue plugin register, but they just don't mount in the other project I want to use them in.

#### Component library

> src/components/Button.vue

```
<template>
  <button
    class="Button"
    :disabled="disabled"
    :class="{'is-block': block, 'is-disabled': disabled }"
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
  name: 'lib-button'
})
export default class extends Vue {
  @Prop() block!: boolean
  @Prop() disabled!: boolean
  @Prop() outline!: boolean
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

> src/components/index.ts

```js
import button from './Button.vue'

const Components: any = {
  button
}

export default Components
```

> src/lib.ts

```js
import _Vue from 'vue'
import Components from './components'

export default {
  install (Vue: typeof _Vue, options: any) {
    for (const key in Components) {
      if (Components.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        Vue.component(`lib-${key}`, Components[key])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "3oilerplate",
  "version": "x.x.x",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "lib": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name 3oilerplate ./src/lib.ts",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "release": "npm run lib && npm version patch && npm publish --access public",
    "release:minor": "npm run lib && npm version minor && npm publish --access public",
    "release:major": "npm run lib && npm version major && npm publish --access public"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "src/",
    "public/",
    "*.json",
    "*.js"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/3oilerplate.common.js",
```

Here I use the `release` command, which also executes the `lib` command, which builds a lib version for my comp library.

#### Other project

> src/main.ts

```js
import Lib from '3oilerplate'
Vue.use(Lib)
```

Here I'm importing my compiled Typescript Vue library (`3oilerplate.common.js`)

> src/Main.vue

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    <Body>
      <lib-button>Test</lib-button>
  </Layout>
</template>
```

And here I'm trying to use a component from the imported Vue plugin, it doesn't give me errors in the browser, so the component registers, it just doesn't mount in the browser.

Please help me out, really hope someone sees what I'm doing wrong.